# issues in configuring WordPress website on a Windows server

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, configuration, web-config

I have moved my WordPress website to a Windows server, but I am facing an issue. If I place the code for this in web.config

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
```

then website gives an error 500.19 **HTTP 500.19 Internal Server Error Config invalid**

If I remove this code from web.config then website only works on permalinks that starts with index.php like index.php/opening-timings/

Comment: unless you need COM never host on windows

Comment: please check IIS server rewrite module is disabled by default, so if it's disabled than enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to use as below but make sure that you have enabled rewrite rules module on IIS server because by default its on disabled stage.

and you can also refer this link for configuring server wordpress Permalinks

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: please check IIS server rewrite module is disabled by default, so if it's disabled than enable it

Answer (score 0):

Change Permalink format in admin side in **setting** tab click on **Permalink**.
Remove index.php from format.
than URL will come without index.php.

Comment: if i remove index.php, it gives error 404 that page does not found